# Google Spreadsheet chart not pulling information from table correctly

Tags: google-sheets, graph

I have 2 tabs relating to the graph I'm working with. I have multiple graphs all working properly but one in particular. I have tried selecting different ranges to use for the data range, I have tried using different types of graphs. All the same I get the same results. The other graphs use the same information from the same table.

The graph's purpose is to compare the `Highest Price` and the `Lowest Price` per item. [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZzJiDGbFKFMvx4yTuZaEzjMMSGNNANbVlCC94zNYEbs/edit?usp=sharing) is a link to a sample sheet with the same information as the original. Thank you for any help you can give!

[image: Picture of the best results I can get when playing around with the graph's data ranges.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

values needs to be numeric not text string so in worst case a conversion is needed:

```
=ArrayFormula({INDEX(SPLIT(F4:F13, " "),,1), INDEX(SPLIT(G4:G13, " "),,1)})
```

and then you can plot your chart...

[image]

Comment: Thank you again for the awesome help and quick response! I actually used what you said and converted the original data to a numeric value without the "ISK" and put a `VALUE` inside of the look up formula in the statistic table: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IF(B4:B1004="","",VALUE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B4:B, SORT(QUERY({bulk_market_data!C4:G}, 
 "select Col1,Col5"), 1, 1, 2, 1), 2, 0), 0))) = 0,0,(IF(B4:B1004="","",VALUE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B4:B, SORT(QUERY({bulk_market_data!C4:G}, 
 "select Col1,Col5"), 1, 1, 2, 1), 2, 0), 0))))))`

Comment: I was then able to set the numbers in the item statistic table to a custom format so I can retain the "ISK" and maintain the numeric format for the graph, again thank you!